# Syntax error in SQL with NEW values

Tags: sql, triggers

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER precio_reparaciones
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Reparaciones
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    UPDATE Reparaciones
    SET precio = :NEW.gasto_material * :NEW.tiempo_usado * :NEW.factor
    WHERE :NEW.garantia = 0;
END;
```

SQL Developer shows a syntax error where the first `:NEW` is. (I'm using Oracle Database Express Edition 11g.)

How can I solve it?

Comment: ***WHAT*** RDBMS is this for? Triggers and procedural programming is **highly** vendor-specific - so is this for MySQL? Postgres? IBM DB2? SQL Server? Oracle? What else?!!?!?

Comment: don't you think that if you update the same table in your `update' trigger then this is going in infinity loop??

sorry for this comment .. this is not solution but you are definatly going on infinity loop in this trigger..

Comment: Is there another way to set a column that depends on other ones?

Comment: @Kern Goldstein .. Yep there is way to do this also..
See my post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reply of the comment by @Kern Golstein -

You can change your trigger as below -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER precio_reparaciones
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Reparaciones
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
if :new.garantia = 0 then 
    :new.precio := :NEW.gasto_material * :NEW.tiempo_usado * :NEW.factor;
    end if;
END;
```

Comment: I've changed my trigger and then I've tried to do an update, but in the log appears the following:

Fila 1: ORA-04091: table TIENDA.REPARACIONES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "TIENDA.PRECIO_REPARACIONES", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TIENDA.PRECIO_REPARACIONES'

Comment: @KernGoldstein: That error can only appear if you *still* have that `update` statement in your code. **Not** with the code Pratik posted. You can **not** "`update`" the table that is being changed by the trigger.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't understand what you said. >:

Comment: @KernGoldstein: you can ***not*** have any DML (insert/update/delete/select) statements in your trigger that operator on the table on which the trigger is defined. Please show your **complete** trigger code in the your question. For more information see here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORA-04091

Comment: I mean. I did the update after I compile my trigger; it is a different script. (My trigger code is the same that @pratik garg posted.)

Comment: Ups, excuse me. I forget to enable my trigger. It works fine now.